# SSIS Visual Basic Script Task - Import additional VB file

Tags: vb.net, import, ssis

I've got a script task written in Visual Basic, and I've got a separate VB file with a few functions in it. I've copied the functions file into the script task, and its showing up as so:

[image]

However, I cannot for the life of me get the class properly referenced in ScriptMain.vb. The Functions file is as follows:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Functions

    Public Function validateXMLDoc()
        ...
    End Function

End Class
```

I have the following in ScriptMain:

```
Imports Functions
```

But I get an error saying the namespace can't be found. I'm not sure if I have my Functions class set up wrong, or if I'm simply referencing it incorrectly. Any help is mega appreciated!

**Update:** I changed the import statement to the following:

```
Imports st_15aa6eds784g7df.vbproj.Functions
```

It now imports successfully, but I still can't reference the functions within the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the functions shared. Once I did the following in Functions.vb it worked great:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Functions

    Public Shared Function validateXMLDoc()
        ...
    End Function

End Class
```

Then reference it in MainScript:

```
Imports funct = st_15aa6eds784g7df.vbproj.Functions
..
...
..
isValid = funct.validateXMLDoc()
```